# Docker not working on "localhost/subpage"

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker.
I set up my custom environment for Wordpress development, everything set up correctly.
`localhost` is showing the expected and Wordpress can connect to the database.

But the `localhost/subpage` returns 404 error, did I miss anything?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  webserver:
    build:
      context: ./bin/webserver
    container_name: 'dp-server'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - /Users/albert/www/:/var/www/html
  mysql:
    build: ./bin/mysql
    container_name: 'dp-mysql'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN apt-get -y update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

#Install mysql integration
RUN apt-get -y install libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-0 mysql-client
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_sqlite
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you go to a page other than index?

Comment: I got 404 error. Page does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Login to wordpress admin panel

Go to Settings » Permalinks, and select post name radio button ( verify the ip / dns name given )
Then click on save button.

If that doesn't solve then make changes in `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The `.htaccess` file goes in the same folder as `wp-content/` and `wp-admin/` etc...